# Using cursor to populate a new field by concatenating existing fields

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, concatenation

I have a question for a current assignment that requires me to write a script that will add a new field to a feature class and then use a cursor to populate the new field by concatenating five other fields (name, address, city, stateabb, zipCode). The new field is FullAdd and will be the full mailing address in one field from the information that is already in the table.

I need help with the update cursor part of my code.

How do I make it write the concatenation to the new field?

I've tried so many things after the 'with cursor' statement and for loop and have no idea where to go next!

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"C:\mygdb.gdb"
env.overwriteOutput = True
# Set up search cursor for hospitals FC
# Make the hospitals FC a lyr
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Hospitals", "Hospitals_lyr")


# Add the new field
arcpy.AddField_management("Hospitals_lyr", "FullAdd", "TEXT")

fields = ['NAME', 'ADDRESS', 'CITY', 'ST_ABREV', 'ZIP_CODE', "FullAdd"]

cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Hospitals_lyr", fields)

try:
  with cursor as updateCursor:
    for row in updateCursor:
      name = row[0]
      address = row[1]
      city = row[2]
      stateAbb = row[3]
      zipCode = row[4]
      FullAdd = row[5]
      FullAdd = str(name + " " + address + " " + city + ", " \
      stateAbb     + " " + zipCode)
      updateCursor.updateRow(row)


  # Copy feature lyr back to disk
  arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Hospitals_lyr", "Hospitals_2")
  print "done"

except:
    print "Error"
```

Comment: What happens if you remove your try/except statements and run the code that you have presented?

Comment: Your `try: except:` is removing all useful debugging information. This is known as the [diaper/nappy pattern](http://mike.pirnat.com/2009/05/09/the-diaper-pattern-stinks/) of exception handling. You shouldn't do this in general and *especially* do not do this when posting code questions to GIS-SE as it makes answering your question so much harder.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My apologies. I'm working through a book for a course that I'm taking and it has us use this, but I definitely see the disadvantage of it and I'm going to cease its use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `row[5]` (the new field) to the concatenated value:

```
with cursor as updateCursor:
    for row in updateCursor:
      name = row[0]
      address = row[1]
      city = row[2]
      stateAbb = row[3]
      zipCode = row[4]
      row[5] = str(name + " " + address + " " + city + ", " \
                   stateAbb + " " + zipCode)
      updateCursor.updateRow(row)
```